# How to send string data from textbox to another textbox in any pages?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

```
index page

 Text_box_1   |_"string data"_|  [submit button] 

when submitted

Another page

 Text_box_2  |_"Show string data from text_box_1"_|
```

It necessary to use a database?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx) variable for transfering the one page text detail to other page

**Index Page**

```
Session["txtvalue"]=txtIndex.Text.Trim();
```

In Other page access this Session variable as

```
if(Session["txtvalue"].ToString()!="")
{
  txtOther.Text=Session["txtvalue"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.If i want to show the data in text-box_2(other page) until someone input data in text-box_1 and click the submit button.

Comment: @AunNuaRambutan Could you explain more what data U want to show in text-box2 until someone input data in text-box_1 and click the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You can also transfer data between asp.net web pages using query string. 
Visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx